# Fallos en mis aplicaciones al pasar a PHP 8

Tags: php

Tengo el código siguiente para obtener el día de la semana en castellano, que se llama desde otro script pasándo el argumento así, dia_semana(2022-01-12):

```
function dia_semana ($fecha) 
{
    $diasem=explode('-',$fecha);
    $dia=$diasem[2];
    $mes=$diasem[1];
    $ano=$diasem[0];
    $dias = array(D, L, M, X, J, V, S);
   return $dias[date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))];
}
```

Estaba funcionando hace años en PHP 7.1, pero al cambiar de hosting con PHP 8, me tira el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "D" in
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/funciones.php:124 Stack
> trace: #0
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/maniobra.php(124):
> dia_semana() #1 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/funciones.php on line
> 124`

---

Lo hice también como dices con las `""` en los días, pero nada

---

```
function dia_semana ($fecha) 
{
    $diasem=explode('-',$fecha);
    $dia=$diasem[2];
    $mes=$diasem[1];
    $ano=$diasem[0];
    $dias = array(D, L, M, X, J, V, S);
   return $dias[date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))];
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "D" in
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/funciones.php:124 Stack
> trace: #0
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/maniobra.php(124):
> dia_semana() #1 {main} thrown in

```
function dia_semana ($fecha) 
{
    $diasem=explode('-',$fecha);
    $dia=$diasem[2];
    $mes=$diasem[1];
    $ano=$diasem[0];
    $dias = array("D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S");
   return $dias[date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))];
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "D" in
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/funciones.php:124 Stack
> trace: #0
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/admin/maniobra.php(124):
> dia_semana() #1 {main} thrown in

Comment: No se porque te funcionaba en el otro php, seguramente porque tenias los errores deshabilitados... mira de cambiar esto: `$dias = array(D, L, M, X, J, V, S);` por esto: `$dias = array("D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S");` y seguramente te saltaras el error, pero no tengo claro si esos acronimos te van a funcionar como pretendes porque no son en ingles y quizas ahi tienes problemas, luego el date lo haces con "w" que te devolvera un numero y luego el return dudo que te devuelva nada porque ese array no creo que contenga nada, le falta asociar claves con nombres seguramente asi "1" => "Domingo"

Comment: ¿Dices que con los guiones tambien te ha dado el mismo error?  ¿u otro error?  El mismo mismo lo dudo un poco.

Comment: Dices que probaste entrecomillando el nombre de los días. "Pero nada". Qué significa  eso? Al entrecomillar no te puede haber dado el mismo error. Usar una constante no declarada antes de php 8 se coercionaba a un string. Ahora tira una excepción (y una excepción no capturada siempre se coerciona a un error fatal)

Comment: Si pones las comillas a los items de `$dias = array("D", "L", ..., "S");`, que es como debe ser, y luego llamas a la función, por ejemplo: `echo dia_semana('2022-02-22');` devuelve `M` comprobado. ¿Será que le estás mandando un formato de fecha incorrecto?

Comment: Basándome en lo que has puesto en una respuesta (que no deberia ser tal, sino que tenias que [edit] la pregunta y agregar esa nueva información, y **no** como una respuesta a la pregunta), en lo que dice @aeportugal, y en mi propia versión con las comillas que tambien funciona bien, diria que **no estas enseñándonos la función correcta**, o bien el sitio correcto que tenemos que corregir.  Te animo a crear un PHP con tan solo la funcion con las comillas y la ejecutes y veras que funciona bien. Por lo tanto el error no esta alli aunque lo parezca. Revisa bien la linea 124 de funciones.php.

Comment: De paso haz el [tour] y así aprenderás como funciona el tema de las preguntas y respuestas y los comentarios, y te ganarás una medalla!

Comment: Si te da el mismo mensaje con las comillas, quiere decir que no estás guardando los cambios, porque cuando te dice: `Undefined constant "D" in ...` significa que precisamente hay una letra `D` sin comillas.

Answer (score 0):

De por sí tu código tiene algunos errores, pero al margen de ello no sé por qué te complicas la vida si todo eso lo puedes hacer más sencillo.

De esta manera:

```
function dia_semana ($fecha) {
    $dias = array('L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D');
    $dia = $dias[(date('N', strtotime($fecha))) - 1];
    return $dia;
}
```

echo dia_semana("2021-12-13");

Y sobre tu código, al igual que todos hice lo mismo, le puse comillas al `array` y funciona. Tendrías que mostrar que es lo que hay en los dos archivos PHP que se muestran en tu error. Allí podría estar la explicación.

```
function dia_semana ($fecha) {
    $diasem=explode('-',$fecha);
    $dia=$diasem[2];
    $mes=$diasem[1];
    $ano=$diasem[0];
    $dias = array("D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S");
   return $dias[date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))];
}
```

Funciona!!